# How to make a H.323 trunk in Asterisk 15

Tags: asterisk, h.323

I'm trying to make a H.323 trunk in asterisk 15 (in a remote server with Ubuntu server 16 installed) with ooh323 addon, to test if works I've the softphone ekiga on my local machine. But when I call to test it not even entry the call, the Asterisk CLI doesn't show any useful information, infact doesn't show anything and the log always are empty even I put it explicitly in the ooh323.conf.

In simple words,I just want to call a h323 extension and hear the classic "hello world". Here's my configuration:

ooh323.conf:

```
[general] 
port = 1720
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0 
disallow=all 
allow=alaw 
dtmfmode=inband
gatekeeper = DISABLE 
context=default


[307]
type=friend
context=default
host=my server ip
port=1720
disallow=all 
allow=alaw,g729,gsm,slinear
```

extension.conf:

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
autofallthrough=yes
clearglobalvars=no

[default]
exten => _X!,1,Dial(H323/${EXTEN}@307) 
exten => _X!,2,Playback(hello-world)
```

Any help is useful, thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**
Now the calls come in, but I get:

```
 chan_ooh323.c:1975 ooh323_onReceivedSetup: Unacceptable ip 187.155.24.149
```

Any ideas?

Comment: h323 protocol is not something that can be "setuped" without specialized knowledge, sorry. Use sip or read more about h323 standart.